# What font is used in the Stack Overflow logo (2008-2015)?

Tags: support, logo, fonts

What font is used in the Stack Overflow logo in place at the time this question was asked (between 2008 and 2015)?

[image: SO logo in 2008-2015]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's called [FF DIN](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/ff-din-font-fontfont).

[image: FF DIN font samples]

Answer (score 17):

Just to confirm — it is [FF Din](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/ff-din-font-fontfont), as Ólafur noted.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest trying [What the Font?](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont)

Comment: Closest match http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/capearcona/ca-bnd/bold/

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the official **FF Din**, as Ólafur said, these are the closest matches I found installed on my computer:

Leelawadee:
[image: Leelawadee]

Euphemia:
[image: Euphemia]

I don't know what these fonts came with, but here are some possible candidates on my system that comes with a bunch of fonts:

- Windows 7 Professional SP1
- MS Office Professional Plus 2010
- Adobe Reader 9.5.1