# What fonts does the StackOverflow logo use?

Tags: discussion, logo, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What font is used in the Stack Overflow logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21099/what-is-the-name-of-the-font)

What fonts does the StackOverflow logo use? I'm just being curious.