# What's the font used in Meta Stack Exchange logo?

Tags: support, design, logo, fonts

The font used in Meta Stack Exchange exists or it was made specially for the site? If it exists, what's the font name? Thanks.

**Here's the logo itself:**

[image: Meta Stack Exchange logo]

Comment: Protip: if you have questions about the design, adding the design tag will draw the attention of the Stack Exchange designers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is [FF DIN bold](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/fontfont/ff_din_ot_bold/):

[image]

It is the same font family used by [the rest of the original series of sites](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos). Also see [What font is used in the Stack Overflow logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21099/what-font-is-used-in-the-stack-overflow-logo/21103#21103)

Comment: Hmm, [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) thought it was [DIN Next](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/din-next/), but then, all those [DIN 1451](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1451) based fonts look pretty similar.