# What is the font used in the Stack Overflow logo, after it was changed few years ago?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, logo, fonts

What is the font used in the Stack Overflow logo? No, **this is not a duplicate**! This question has been [asked on here before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21099/what-font-is-used-in-the-stack-overflow-logo-2008-2015) but that was 14 years ago and the logo and font have changed since. I'm asking about the so logo as of 2024-03-01 whereas OscarRyz was asking about the old logo.

Old logo:
[image: Old logo]

New logo:
[image]

The 't' and 'f' characters are different in the new logo, and the curvature of some of the letters is different.

It might still be the same font with a few manual tweaks, I'm not sure.

Comment: Um...the font has not changed?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Um...yes the font has changed? https://web.archive.org/web/20100425074516/http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Yes, after clearly zooming in, I can see that the styling of the 't' and 'f' have changed. Since spotting any difference requires a very clear look, I'd recommend embedding zoomed copies of the logos into the question that clearly highlight the differences so others don't jump to the conclusion that they're still the same. It's a common issue that can happen to anyone; I've [been on the receiving end of it](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/why-was-my-question-about-cabin-chimes-on-a-specific-plane-closed-as-primarily-o) before.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the answer were simply "it's the same font but a graphic designer manually tweaked the letters".

Comment: That the answer has changed, doesn't mean the question isn't a duplicate. The questions, perhaps, could be edited to be different, but right now they are, in fact, duplicates. It would be reasonable for a new answer to be posted on the old question with the current information. It would be just as valid an answer there as it would be here.

Comment: @Makyen I would personally disagree with closing a question as a duplicate for that reason. On main sites, [it's allowed](/q/20042/377214) to ask a new question if one finds an old answered question and none of the answers there solve the user's problem, if one clearly links to the old question and explains clearly why the answers there didn't help. This is basically the same thing: there are differences in the logo that make the answer there no longer solve the OP's problem. In fact, I gave the author guidance earlier on how they can make it clearer it's not a duplicate per the linked policy.

Comment: Also, here's another way to think about it: the question you link to is asking about the Stack Overflow logo in place *at the time that question was asked*. A question asking what font it uses at the time *this* question was asked would be a different question from that, provided it has clear evidence in it to show that the font has changed.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog As I said "The questions, perhaps, could be edited to be different, but right now they are, in fact, duplicates." Just evidence that the situation has changed isn't sufficient. The questions need to be actually different, not duplicates. If a new identical answer could be posted on both, effectively identical questions, then they are the same duplicate question. There's really no arguing that, regardless of the fact that the existing answers on the older question are no longer accurate.

Comment: Similar things happen *all the time* for questions on SO as the technology changes. It doesn't mean there should be new questions, but there should be, and commonly are, new answers

Comment: @Makyen I have now edited the earlier question so it explicitly asks about the logo in place at the time it was asked (since all the answers were posted when that was the logo, none of them are invalidated).

Comment: Also, there's nothing that a brand new user can do to indicate that an existing question needs a new answer because the current answers are out of date. The best they can do is to post a new question and hope that draws attention to post an updated answer to the original question.

Comment: There is a "name that font" service (of sorts) on [SE.Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). Use the [`font-identification` tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I think that policy of allowing duplicate questions has not been adopted on all sites (at least on most of the sites I frequent). But I agree with this not being a duplicate because a font change basically means a new logo (even if it's not immediately clear :).

Comment: @Makyen That's why it's so sad answer versions were put on halt.

Comment: Perhaps it's a modified or custom version of [Source Sans Pro](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/typography/), where the 'f' and 't' have the left sides of their cross strokes removed, the 'a' has a slightly less curved shoulder, and the right side of the 't' has an angled terminal (perhaps to mirror the bottom of the Stack Exchange glyph).

Answer (score 16):

The base font didn't change, just the logo & [wordmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordmark) did. The company wordmark (the text-only part of the logo + name) includes a *stylized* version of the company name. There are subtle differences that make it a unique derivative of the font. Not just Stack Overflow, but most companies that use wordmarks will morph the text created by a font by adjusting kerning, and making minor modifications to the glyph. Modified tittles, serifs, crossbars, descender lines, etc are all common. I've even seen wordmarks with "ugly" letters "fixed" (ex, swapping a lowercase "g" to use a hook or a loop, opposite the font).

Marketing people love being unique.

So do trademark lawyers.

---

Stack Overflow publishes a ton of stuff about their fonts & designs over at [StackOverflow.design](https://stackoverflow.design/). Though, they don't make mention of the base font used in the wordmark.

Comment: Rolling back edit. A "tittle" is the dot over the i.

Comment: This is correct. We didn't change fonts. It was just tweaked to remove tension areas and add spacing between the two words.

Comment: Awesome answer, deserves some love... and rep. ;-)